# Binary value calculation based on string length

Tags: python-3.x

Example:
for 4 i need binary value as 0100
for 4a i need binary value as 01001010

I tried but the leading zeros are not coming.

```
field_reset = bin(int(field_reset, 16))[2:]

field_reset = bin(int(field_reset, 16))[2:]
```

leading zeros are not coming.please share me if you have any thoughts.
Thanks!

Comment: what is `field_reset` value initially?

Comment: i am taking field_reset value from xml file. 2 values are mentioned as examples.like that so many values are there i need to calculate all the values.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming `field_reset` value is `4a`.

When you do `field_reset = bin(int(field_reset, 16))[2:]`, you are trimming out the beginning part which contains `0b`. Try below one.

```
aa=bin(int('4a',16))[2:]
aa.zfill(len(aa)+1)
```

Comment: not working.not only for 4a i have taken example as 4a.